# How can I remove the first instance of an object of a given class from an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList<E>`, where `E` has several subclasses. I want to remove the first instance of an object of subclass `T`.

My current implementation relies on an overridden `equals(Object o)` that looks at a constant that is unique to the subclass. Since objects of this subclass are interchangeable, I figured this would be much better than the usual implementations. See below.

```
public class E {
    //Stuff
}
```

```
public class T extends E {
    private static final String UNIQUE_STRING = "blah";
    //More variables
    public T() {
    }

    public static String getUniqueString() {
        return UNIQUE_STRING;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (this.getClass() == o.getClass()) {
            T t = (T) o;
            if (this.getUniqueString().equals(t.getUniqueString())) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    //Also has hashCode() here somewhere, as well as other methods
}
```

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        initialize();
    }

    private static void initialize() {
        E t1 = new T();
        E t2 = new T();
        E t3 = new T();
        List<E> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(t1);
        list.add(t2);
        list.add(t3);
        list.remove(new T());
    }
}
```

Using a `Map<T, Integer>` (or similar) is not feasible because `list` is going to contain other subclasses of `E`, not just `T`, and objects of *those* other subclasses differ in many respects. Only instances of `T` are, for all intents and purposes, interchangeable.

Separating instances of `T` from the list and using a `Map<T, Integer>` would be a major headache due to indexing and whatnot.

Finally, searching each object one by one until I found an instance of `T` (by using `getClass()` and the literal name of the class) seems like it'd be even worse.

My concern is that creating new objects to do this, while functional, is highly inefficient and potentially "dangerous". Is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: Have a look at `instanceof` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `instanceof` is probably what you are looking for.

```
class Scratch {
    static class E {
        //Stuff
    }

    static class T extends E {

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final var arrayList = new ArrayList<>(List.of(new E(), new E(), new E(), new T(), new T(), new E()));
        for (E e : arrayList) {
            if (e instanceof T) {
                arrayList.remove(e);
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(arrayList);
    }
}
```

> [Scratch$E@5b1d2887, Scratch$E@46f5f779, Scratch$E@1c2c22f3, Scratch$T@18e8568, Scratch$E@33e5ccce]

This will continue to work work on subclasses of T as well.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot that was a thing in Java. However, that's still just searching through the list from start to finish until if and when I come across something. Is there no faster method of doing this?

Comment: I would not worry about performance until you see measurable problems. Without changing data structures or adding some auxillary ones to do some bookkeeping there is no faster way to do this. I would also be interested in the problem you are trying to solve with this technique - this may be a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: I'm trying to make a card game. Some cards can be attached to others, to trigger various effects at will, but then they must be discarded. Since they're not immediately used, the cards must be stored somewhere and later removed when the player decides to use them.

Comment: what is the inheritance relationship between the cards? How does this map to the original question?

Comment: @Orion: No, there is no faster method.

Comment: E is the superclass of all "equippable" cards and T is a specific subclass where all the cards are interchangeable. Then there's a larger "Card" class, of which E is a subclass, which contains a subclass that is the superclass of all cards that you can equip stuff to. I simplified the question because I figured any solution would work for any similar situation (hands, decks, discard piles, and so on). Also because explaining all this via text is complicated.

Comment: The question was good. I was wondering the usecase that was the motivation for the performance concerns. Performance will not be anything *near* an issue for something like this and I think your structure seems to express the problem well, which IMO is much more important.

Comment: Ah, I see. The performance concerns were mostly unrelated to the actual use case. I just like optimizing code. The main issue was really the fact that the way I was doing it didn't seem right, even if it worked. It'd been a while since I programmed in Java, so I forgot `instanceof` was a thing.

Answer (score 0):

if you have an extensive list and you're looking for a faster way of doing things, you can use parallel streams of java 8

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final var arrayList = new ArrayList<>(List.of(new E(), new E(), new E(), new T(), new T(), new E()));
       var listWithoutTinstances = arrayList.parallelStream()
                .filter(e -> e instanceOf T)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

make sure you have to use parallel stream instead of simple one , you can check this to learn more:  https://www.baeldung.com/java-when-to-use-parallel-stream

Comment: OP wants to remove only the **first** instance of `T`, therefore it would not work. Also, using a parallel stream is not necessarily a *"a faster way of doing things"*, especially in the case when there are only 6 elements in the pipeline.

Comment: so the for loop can do the doing